# Python String Handling Functions

Tags: python

Is there a specific function that returns true if characters in the string are special characters (ex: #. @. $)? Like, the isalpha() function returns true if all the characters in a string are letters.

I have to create a program where I need to ask a user for a string and then my program must print the length of the string, the number of letters, the number of digits and the number of characters that are not letters.

```
counter = 0
num = 0
extra = 0

wrd = raw_input("Please enter a short sentence.")

for i in wrd:
    if i.isalpha():
        counter = counter + 1

print "You have " + str(counter) +" letters in your sentence."

for n in wrd:
    if n.isnumeric():
        num = num + 1

print "You have " + str(num) + " number(s) in your sentence"

for l in wrd:
    extra = extra + 1

print "You have " + str(extra) + " characters that are not letters or numbers."
```

I got the first two parts figured out albeit I'm stuck on the last...I know its easier to just create one while loop but since I already started, I want to stick with three four loops.

Comment: Why not `len(wrd) - counter - num`?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need another function. Since you've already counted the other characters, subtract them from the total:

```
print "You have", len(wrd) - counter - num, "characters that are not letters or numbers."
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a specific function that returns true if characters in the string are special characters (ex: #. @. $)? Like, the isalpha() function returns true if all the characters in a string are letters.

No, but its pretty easy to create your own:

```
import string

def has_special_chars(s):
    return any(c in s for c in string.punctuation)
```

**Test:**

```
>>> has_special_chars("ab@tjhjf$dujhf&")
True
>>> has_special_chars("abtjhjfdujhf")
False
>>>
```

In your case, you would use it like:

```
for l in wrd:
    if has_special_chars(l)
        extra=extra+1
```

---

But as @TigerHawkT3 has already beat me to saying, you should simply use `len(wrd) - counter - num` instead. Its the most canonical and obvious way.

Answer (score 0):

Just to log a generic answer that will apply beyond this context -

```
import string
def num_special_char(word):
    count=0
    for i in word:
        if i in string.punctuation:
            count+=1
    return count

print "You have " + str(num_special_char('Vi$vek!')) + " characters that are not letters or numbers."
```

**Output**

```
You have 2 characters that are not letters or numbers.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one `for` loop with `if`, `elif` and `else`:

```
sentence = raw_input("Please enter a short sentence.")

alpha = num = extra = 0
for character in sentence:
    if character.isspace():
        pass
    elif character.isalpha():
        alpha += 1
    elif character.isnumeric():
        num += 1
    else:
        extra += 1

print "You have {} letters in your sentence.".format(alpha)
print "You have {} number(s) in your sentence".format(num)
print "You have {} characters that are not letters or numbers.".format(extra)
```